# Python 2 Inheriting from calling class and another specified class

Tags: python-2.7, class, matplotlib, super

Here is my setup. This isn't all the code, just the important parts

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

class MyToolbar(NavigationToolbar):
def __init__(self, figure_canvas, parent, main):
    self.toolitems = (
    ('Home', 'Reset Original View', 'home', 'home'),    # (Title, Tooltip, Icon, callback function)
    ('Back', 'Back to previous view', 'back', 'back'),
    ('Forward', 'Forward to next view', 'forward', 'forward'),
    ('Clear', 'Clear all graphs', 'clearIcon', 'on_click_clear_graph'),
    )

    NavigationToolbar.__init__(self, figure_canvas, parent)

    def on_click_clear_graph(self):
        # I need to access calling class' (PlotWindow's) clearAx method here
        super(MyToolbar,self).clearAx() # but this doesn't work

class PlotWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = MyToolbar(self.canvas, self, parent)
    def clearAX(self):
        self.ax.clear()
```

I use the MyToolbar class to add extra tools to the Matplotlib toolbar, but I also need to get access to the variables in the PlotWindow class.

I have been using super() in other parts of the program and I can use it to get access to parent classes but in this case I cannot seem to get it to work.

Am I missing some part of it?

Perhaps if the above code doesn't make sense this example below could be used.

```
class A(SomeOtherInheritedClass):
    # how can I call print_something from class B here 
    # without interfering with SomeOtherInheritedClass
class B():
    a = A()
    def print_something(self):
        print "something"
```

Comment: In order for `super` to work, class `B` would need to inherit from  class `A`. This would be one possible option (but one would need to be careful not to override existing attributes of `SomeOtherInheritedClass`). Otherwise, you may monkeypatch the `on_click_clear_graph` method inside the PlotWindow class or - since you are using Qt here - use signals and slots to connect to the methods of choice. Since the code is no [mcve], I cannot test anything and hence not provide a full answer.

Comment: The `MyToolbar` class gets a reference to the `PlotWindow` instance that created it via the `parent` argument to `__init__`. If its parent class doesn't store that reference somewhere that can be accessed (e.g. as `self.parent` or something), you could store it yourself. I don't think inheritance makes any sense for the relationship between the toolbar and the window. The `parent` relationship there is not the same as being a parent class (it just uses the same term).